# Inefficient usage of string.format?

Tags: c#, strings

I have some sample code where I used `string.Format` but after reading about benchmark performances by other people I believe that it may be better to do multiple `appends` by a `StringBuilder`

Here is the scenario:

In my `gridView`, I have a function called before a `databind`. The function looks like such:

```
public string getColumnText(String myParam)
{
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    return sb.Append(string.Format("<a href='javascript:Global.someFunction(\"{0}\");'>{1}</a>", myParam).ToString();
}
```

Is this a better alternative?

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
sb.Append("<a href = 'javascript:Global.someFunction(\"");
sb.Append(myParam"); etc...
```

Let's assume that this function will be called 10,000 times.

Comment: It doesn't directly matter how many times the function will be called. (And it's not even clear what exactly do you mean by that: Is that 10,000 times per year? Or per second? Or something completely else?) What matters is whether the first method is too slow for your performance requirements.

Comment: I would suggest running benchmarks on both and see what the results are.

Comment: @svick I don't see how its not clear. I mentioned that my function is going to be performed before `gridview.databind()` is called so implying that 10K cooresponds to the number of entries in my gridView

Comment: @Rhs Ok, but that wasn't the main point I was making. The most important thing is: is this actually too slow for you? If not, write what's most readable and don't worry about performance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A `StringBuilder` is useful when you're constructing a `string` where a loop will be directly effecting it, i.e. if you were appending several strings together within a loop, I'd recommend using a `StringBuilder`. Here's an example of where you might use a `StringBuilder`.

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder()
for (int i = 0; i < someItems.length; i++)
{
    sb.AppendFormat("{0} is item index {1}\n", someItems[i], i);
}
return sb.ToString();
```

There are some overheads with `string.Format`, however they aren't huge, especially not in your case. Unless you're concerned about micro-optimisations, I think in this scenario it all falls down to readability, and which you prefer.

An alternative method, which would be slightly faster than `string.Format` is to simply concatenate the string together, like so:

```
public string getColumnText(String myParam)
{
    return "<a href='javascript:Global.someFunction(\"" + myParam + "\");'>" + myParam + "</a>";
}
```

You may also want to consider ensuring it's *safe* for your desired output, i.e. do you need to escape quotation marks for `myParam`, or does it need to be HTML encoded?

Comment: I disagree, string.Format is much easier for my eyes too parse. Having a concatenated mess of variables and text is hard to look at and a pain to manage down the road.

Comment: I agree; I didn't imply using string concatenation with `+` was easier to read, I said it was slightly faster. I personally prefer `string.Format` for readability.